# ACF: How to make get_field() ignore the main wp query?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have a filter applied to the main WP query via a load action (`pre_get_posts`) for all the admin pages in my website. It simply limits the edit (listing page) to show records created only by the specific user currently logged in.

The problem is that this then stops ACF functions from working properly. I have a function called by another action that is loading via acf/init. The function queries a repeater field with `get_field()`. The value returned by `get_field()` is not the expected array but just integers. If I remove this filter code below the problem doesn’t occur.

```
// The filter code that shows only the current authors posts
add_action(‘pre_get_posts’, ‘query_set_only_author’);
function query_set_only_author( $wp_query ) {
    if( is_admin() && get_current_user_role()==”required_role” ) {
        if ( basename($_SERVER[‘PHP_SELF’])==”edit.php”){
            $wp_query->set( ‘author’, $current_user->ID );
       }
    }
}
```

So my question is, it seems get_field is having my general edit page filter applied to it as well, so how to I make it not use the filtered query ?

Comment: I don't know if ACF sets anything you can check when it's running a query, if it does then I'd use that in the `pre_get_posts` filter.  Otherwise I would use a singleton class and set a flag variable when calling the function that uses `get_field` then check for that variable in the `pre_get_posts` filter

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding wp_query->is_main_query() to my clauses before I set the query update.  Ie...

```
// The filter code that shows only the current authors posts
add_action(‘pre_get_posts’, ‘query_set_only_author’);
function query_set_only_author( $wp_query ) {
    if( is_admin() && get_current_user_role()==”required_role” && $wp_query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ( basename($_SERVER[‘PHP_SELF’])==”edit.php”){
            $wp_query->set( ‘author’, $current_user->ID );
       }
    }
```